# titleFormat year and month into 2 div fullcalendar <div>Year</div> <div>Month</div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I have a problem! I need to separate the title of calendar in 2 divs. I need Year in top page and month in top calendar. I can do this with `angular.element` but i don't understand why the function runs 2 times.

Here is my code.

**Config FullCalendar**

```
            titleFormat: {
                     month: 'MMMM YYYY'

            },
            header: {
                left: 'title,prev'
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
```

Now in `eventAfterAllRender` i put my code to separate and change position of month and year

```
 eventAfterAllRender: function (){            
        var fecha=angular.element('.fc-left').text().split(" ");   
        var mes=fecha[0];
        var ano=fecha[1];        
        console.log("veces");

    angular.element('.fc-left').html('<div><h2>'+ano+'</h2><button type="button" class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow"></span></button></div>');
    angular.element('.fc-center').html("<h2>"+mes+"</h2>");
    },
```

But the function runs 2 times, so Month and year are Undefined!
Also  I have tried to put the function inside ready but is not ok.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
var fecha=angular.element('.fc-left').text().split(" "); 
      var mes=fecha[0];
      var ano=fecha[1];      
      console.log("veces");

  angular.element('.fc-left').html('<div><h2>'+ano+'</h2><button type="button" class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow"></span></button></div>');
   angular.element('.fc-center').html("<h2>"+mes+"</h2>");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try add you code in the `viewRender` instead of the `eventAfterAllRender` callback and split the view.title

This way your code will run only when the view change e.g. moving next day or month, even if you don't have events

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/

example

```
viewRender: function ( view ){      
    var fecha = view.title.split(" ");   
    var mes = fecha[0];
    var ano = fecha[1];        

angular.element('.fc-left').html('<div><h2>'+ano+'</h2><button type="button" class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow"></span></button></div>');
angular.element('.fc-center').html("<h2>"+mes+"</h2>");
},
```